# Thymeleaf with JSP - return ModelAndView

Tags: java, thymeleaf

In our project we use JSP, but we're migrating to Thymeleaf.

For the new controllers which are rendered via Thymeleaf we use following syntax:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/thymeleaf", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html; charset=utf-8")
@ResponseBody
public void index(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    TemplateEngine templateEngine = createThymeleafTemplateEngine();

    WebContext ctx = new WebContext(request, response, context);
    createModel(ctx, getBasicPageModel(request, response));

    templateEngine.process("index", ctx, response.getWriter());
}
```

in `createThymeleafTemplateEngine` we have following code:

```
private TemplateEngine createThymeleafTemplateEngine() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();

    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/thymeleaf/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);

    TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

    return templateEngine;
}
```

So it's obvious that to render Thymeleaf we create templateEngine and then using that we generate template as an output to response.

But now I need to use it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/thymeleaf2", method= RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView index1(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    WebContext ctx = new WebContext(request, response, context);
    createModel(ctx, getBasicPageModel(request, response));

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("index");
    mav.addAllObjects(ctx.getVariables());

    return mav;
}
```

But unfortunately this does not work. The system tries to find index.jsp and obviously it fails. It is not an option for us to set Thymeleaf as a default renderer for the whole project (as JSP will stop working). So is there any option to return ModelAndView from Thymeleaf directly?

Comment: In case it helps... If you use `String s = templateEngine.process("index", ctx);`, this gives you the post-processed Thymeleaf template. I don't know much (anything) about Spring's `ModelAndView` - but once you have the independently processed HTML, can you add that to the `ModelAndView` - or send it as the JSP response body?

Comment: thanks for a tip. I made it that way - rendered Thymeleaf into string and then rendered empty JSP to satisfy ModelAndView. Works well.

Answer (score 0):

Look that when you are using your function createThymeleafTemplateEngine, you set the prefix. So, the template engine can find your thymeleaf pages.

When you are using the thymeleaf to do the job, you are no setting this attribute.
By default, the framework will try to find your pages in src/main/resources/templates and thats why can't find it.

If your are using spring boot, add in your application.properties:

spring.thymeleaf.prefix: classpath:/thymeleaf/